# What happens when we remove the SnapshotIdentifier from our Cloudformation config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudformation

When we spun up our Cloudformation stack, we restored our DBCluster from a snapshot. We are now in the process of updating our stack.

What will Cloudformation do with our DBCluster if we remove the SnapshotIdentifier key from our config? Let's assume here that we are not using stack policies.

[The docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-snapshotidentifier) show that updating that parameter would cause a replacement. However, that's not what we want, and we wouldn't be sure what to do exactly to prevent that.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this change ?  By removing the snapshot identifier you are basically telling cloud formation that you want an empty db... Which it could only provide by doing a replacement.

Comment: Well we actually don't want to update the cluster at all, but rather update other resources. We don't have the original snapshot anymore. When we  tried to use that identifier anyway, Cloudformation started complaining since it couldn't find the snapshot. This also led us to think that supplying the initial snapshot would reset the database to that state..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changing the attribute DBSnapshotIdentifier will indeed result in a replacement of the AWS::RDS::DBInstance.

Behind the scenes, CloudFormation (CFN) stores the current configuration of all resources. When you update a resource CFN does a describe call of those resources, and compares it to the stored values.

Only if values actually change, resources will be updated. That said, as long as you do not update the DBSnapshotIdentifier property, the database should not be replaced.

With RDS, this behaveour of CFN can cause annoying problems, especially if the RDS endpoints change.

This is what we currently consider good practice:

1. Establish an own RDS stack, which is seperated from the rest. Export the RDS endpoint as "RDSEndpoint-$Version". Set Version as a parameter.
2. Point your applications to the correct RDS endpoint. Using the export from the previous stack or using a Route53 entry for this would be easiest.
3. If you need make changes to the RDS instances that cause a replacement, do them on a new RDS stack, change $Version to something else.
4. Once everything is okay. Change the RDS endpoint in your applications (or change the Route53 entry, whatever suits you best).

Common problems are:

- Duration of data migration between databases - if your application does not support this, you may run into problems.
- RDS change operations are generally a bit slow. Often it is faster to just run mysqldump + mysql (in case of MySQL) instead of relying on AWS instances.
- Loss of credentials when switching over to a new stack (you should have documented the credentials, but consider this anyway).

If you are looking for a one-time-solution for your specific problem, here is one (with possible downtime):

1. Take your application to read-only or maintenance mode (if the application does not support this, this might be causing the downtime).
2. (Manually or with RDS Snapshot) create a dump of your database.
3. Update your DB with your new CloudFormation template
4. Restore from your dump.
5. Switch your application to production. If the endpoint changed, switch that too.